# How can I reference a variable within a method in another method in the same class (Java)?

Tags: java

Say I have a method under a class:

```
public void setNetForce(Planet[] planets) {
            this.xNetForce = 0;
            this.yNetForce = 0;
            for(Planet p:planets) {
                if (p == this) {
                    continue;
                }
                this.xNetForce += this.calcPairwiseForceX(p);
                this.yNetForce += this.calcPairwiseForceY(p);
            }

        }
```

Now I want to use the value of xNetforce and yNetForce in another method of the same class, how can I do it?

Comment: would like to consider making that `xNetForce ` as global variable ?

Comment: The `this.xNetForce` idiom indicates the variable is scoped to the class instance. Any instance method can access this variable.

Comment: Looking at the code I would say they are already class level variables.

Comment: @DavidG not class level, instance level. Class level means static.

Comment: Yes okay. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable

Comment: @DavidG and quoting the wiki page: "Thus in some languages, static member variable or static member function are used synonymously with or in place of "class variable" or "class function", but these are not synonymous across languages. These terms are commonly used in Java, C#, and C++, where class variables and class methods are declared with the static keyword, and referred to as static member variables or static member functions." Sorry for being picky here :D

Comment: No problem Mena, I was agreeing with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `this.xNetForce` in your method implies that there are *instance* variable.

So they can be used in other *non-static* method the same way you have used in your method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xNetforce and yNetForce in another method of the same class by moving the initialisation

```
this.xNetForce = 0;
this.yNetForce = 0;
```

outside `setNetForce()` method that is at the class level in this way you will make it global or available to whole class.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you have a **Planet** object that keeps it's **xNetForce** and **yNetForce** private/public variables. Therefore, if you modify these values in one method, they will be **stay modified within the object scope**.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.xNetForce = 0;
this.yNetForce = 0;
```

By this two line it seems   `xNetForce` and  `yNetForce` already in the the global scope (instance level )

So you can happily use them in any method of this same class

But if you want to know what if those variable was declared in this method, like:

```
public void setNetForce(Planet[] planets) {
int xNetForce = 0;
int yNetForce = 0;
......................
}
```

and  then how to use them another method?

Answer is **You cant**.

Answer (score 0):

1. To access values of varaibles, ubiquitously available to all instances of class, make xNetForce and yNetForce, static and let all instances play with them.
2. Don't forget the case of many threads playing with them and you misses their latest value. You should program to maintain their access integrity.
3. If non static, your single instance can play with variables throughout the life.

Answer (score 0):

`this.xNetForce` means this variable is the member of this class.

Any variable that is accessed by 'this' clause is actually a class member. A class member can be accessed from any other method of the same class.
Example:

```
public class Physics
{

    private int xNetForce;

    public void setNetForce(Planet[] planets) {
                this.xNetForce = 0;

            }

    public void setNetForceValue( int val)
    {
           this.xNetForce=val;
    }

}
```

If you declare the class variable as static member then all of the objects of this class will share the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void setXNetForce () {
    this.xNetForce=xNetForce;
}

    public void setYNetForce () {
    this.yNetForce=yNetForce;
}

    public void getXNetForce() {
 return this.xNetForce;
}
 public void getYNetForce() {
  return this.yNetForce;
}
```

Use a getter and setter